# How can I prevent the "random" gray row from displaying in my DGV?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have AllowUserToAddRows set to false in my DataGridView. Yet, when I navigate to the last row via the directional arrow keys, the top row scrolls out of sight and a new gray row appears at the bottom.

How can I prevent this? I want all of my rows to be visible no matter how far up, down, to the left or right I move the cursor.

Note: Navigating through the cells horizontally doesn't cause a problem - there is no gray column added when I do that. I want the rows/vertical functionality to be the same as that.

Comment: What do you mean "I want all of my rows to be visible"?  Do you have just enough rows to fit the size of the grid?  No vertical scrollbar?

Comment: Yes; ScrollBars = None. Number of columns will always be the same (as is usually the case); number of rows the same UNLESS a user adds rows (programmatically), in which case the rows still use the same amount of space (each row's height is reduced when a new row is added in this way). I just don't want any "automatic" gray rows.

Answer (score 1):

So one approach to this would be do the following:

On the `DataGridView`, set the properties`AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` to **false**

Also, set `AutoSizeRowsMode` to **None**

Handle the resize of the `DataGridView` like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rowHeight = (dataGridView1.Height - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight) / 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height = rowHeight;
    }
}
```

In my example, the Form1_Load event  just adds some rows and then calls the DGV's resize to make everything look right initially, but you could handle this different ways.  Something like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }
    dataGridView1_Resize(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I've already got those properties set that way, and am dynamically changing the height of the rows based on gridheight / rowcount, but I'll try it.

Comment: Interesting.  Works fine in my demo app.

Comment: Could it be an OS difference? I'm on XP.

Comment: Maybe.  Don't know.  I'm using Win7 for my test.